# How to set HttpOnly response header using nginx?

Tags: node.js, security, nginx, cookies, httponly

We are using node js and nginx as Web Server.

We want to restrict XSS attack by mitigating script execution that uses Cookies.

How can I secure Cookies by adding HttpOnly flags in nginx settings?

Answer (score 0):

From Nginx version **1.19.3** you can use `proxy_cookie_flags` to add additional flags for your cookies.

For all cookie use:

`proxy_cookie_flags ~ secure samesite=strict;`

For some of the cookies you can use (or regex):

`proxy_cookie_flags one httponly;`

Check more in documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_flags

Answer (score -2):

Edit your virtualhost file:-

> sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-enable/example.conf

Add Below Line under server block:-

**add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";**

Example:-

```
server {
    server_name     a.com;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    root            /var/www/a/;

}
```